# How to assign individual values to be summed up for different "right" answers?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

On a simple test, how does one assign a unique value to be incremented, so instead of adding 1 on to the score for every right answer, a question might be weighted more than the rest? Have tried to separate the tests first and the problem might have been easier to solve but am unsure as to how to proceed.

```
<body>
<h1>Test for Stroke and Diabetes</h1>
<form name="combitest">
  <p style="color:green;font-size:20px">
    History of Stroke</p>
  <ul style="margin-top: 3pt">
    <label><input type="radio" name="hststroke" value="Yes">Yes</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="hststroke" value="No">No</label><br>
  </ul>

  <p style="color:green;font-size:20px">
    Age</p>
  <ul style="margin-top: 3pt">
    <label><input type="radio" name="age" value="<84">less than 84</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="age" value=">84">greater than 84</label><br>
  </ul>

  <p style="color:green;font-size:20px">
    Female</p>
  <ul style="margin-top: 3pt">
    <label><input type="radio" name="female" value="Yes">Yes</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="female" value="No">No</label><br>
  </ul>

  <p style="color:green;font-size:20px">
    History of diabetes mellitus</p>
  <ul style="margin-top: 3pt">
    <label><input type="radio" name="hstdiabetesmellitus" value="Yes">Yes</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="hstdiabetesmellitus" value="No">No</label><br>
  </ul>

  <p style="color:green;font-size:20px">
    History of congestive heart failure</p>
  <ul style="margin-top: 3pt">
    <label><input type="radio" name="hstcongestiveheart failure" value="Yes">Yes</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="hstcongestiveheart failure" value="No">No</label><br>
  </ul>

  <p style="color:green;font-size:20px">
    History of hypertension</p>
  <ul style="margin-top: 3pt">
    <label><input type="radio" name="hsthypertension" value="Yes">Yes</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="hsthypertension" value="No">No</label><br>
  </ul>

  <p style="color:green;font-size:20px">
    Proteinuria</p>
  <ul style="margin-top: 3pt">
    <label><input type="radio" name="proteinuria" value="Yes">Yes</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="proteinuria" value="No">No</label><br>
  </ul>

  <p style="color:green;font-size:20px">
    EGFR less than 45 or end-stage renal disease</p>
  <ul style="margin-top: 3pt">
    <label><input type="radio" name="eGFRlt45orendstagerenal" value="Yes">Yes</label><br>
    <label><input type="radio" name="eGFRlt45orendstagerenal" value="No">No</label><br>
  </ul>
 
  <p> Score for test 1 (Stroke) =   <span class="res"></span><br><br>
  <p> Score for test 2 (Diabetes) = <span class="res"></span><br><br>
  <p> Score for test 2 (Diabetes) = <span class="res"></span><br><br>
  <input type="reset" value="Clear Answers">
    
  </form>
  </body>
```

```
  <script>
      const ca=[
   ["Yes", "Yes"],
   [">84", "<84"],
   ["Yes",       ,"Yes"],
   ["Yes", "Yes"],
   ["Yes",       , "No"],
   ["Yes"],
   ["Yes"],
   ["Yes", "No"]
];
let spans=[...document.querySelectorAll('span.res')];
document.querySelector("input[type=reset]").onclick=ev=>spans.forEach(sp=>sp.textContent="");
document.querySelector("form").onchange=ev=>{
  let cnt=[0,0,0], res=[0,0,0], uls=document.querySelectorAll('form ul');  
  ca.forEach((c,i)=>{
    c.forEach((ca,j)=>{ var q;
      // evrything happens here:
      // * the count is incremented for each question (cnt[])
      // * if the answer fits, the score is incremented too (res[])
      ca && ++cnt[j] && (q=uls[i].querySelector("input:checked")) && q.value==ca && ++res[j]
    });
  });
  res.forEach((r,i)=>spans[i].textContent=(200*r/cnt[i]).toFixed(2))
}
  </script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

OK, here is another re-write of the whole thing. :D

I restructured your HTML markup. It was far too verbose and repetitive. I now generate everything from the object `questions`. In it you will find the questions themselves with all possible answer options (can be any number of answers). The answer array (property `a` within each questions object) has the following format: `[["possible answer value", [test1score,test2score,test3score]], ["next possible answer",[...]], ...]`. Depending on the chosen answer one of the points array will be added to the results array `res`. The total sum will then be shown in the three `.res` spans.

```js
const questions=[  // questions,            answers with their associated points:
   {q:"History of Stroke",                  a:[["Yes",[10,10, 0]],["No" ,    [ 0, 0, 0]]]},
   {q:"Age",                                a:[[">84",[20,20, 0]],["<84",    [ 0, 0, 0]]]},
   {q:"Female",                             a:[["Yes",[10, 0,30]],["No" ,    [ 0, 0, 0]]]},
   {q:"History of diabetes mellitus",       a:[["Yes",[20,50, 0]],["No" ,    [ 0, 0, 0]]]},
   {q:"History of congestive heart failure",a:[["Yes",[30, 0,50]],["No" ,    [ 0, 0, 0]]]},
   {q:"History of hypertension",            a:[["Yes",[30, 0, 0]],["No" ,    [ 0, 0, 0]]]},
   {q:"Body mass index",                    a:[["<23",[ 0, 0, 0]],["23...28",[20,20,30]],[">28" ,[50,60,40]]]},
   {q:"Proteinuria",                        a:[["Yes",[10, 0, 0]],["No",     [ 0, 0, 0]]]},
   {q:"EGFR less Than 45 or end-stage renal desease",
                                            a:[["Yes",[0,  0, 0]],["No",     [ 0, 0, 0]]]}
];
const frm =document.querySelector("form");
// create questions block first:
frm.innerHTML=questions.map(q=>{
  let nam=q.q.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g,"").substr(0,12)
  return `<p style="color:green;font-size:20px">${q.q}</p>
          <ul style="margin-top: 3pt">${q.a.map(([a])=>`<label><input type="radio" name="${nam}" value="${a}">${a}</label>`).join('<br>\n')}</ul>`;
}).join('\n')+frm.innerHTML;

let spans=[...document.querySelectorAll('span.res')];
document.querySelector("input[type=reset]").onclick=ev=>spans.forEach(sp=>sp.textContent="");
frm.onchange=ev=>{
  let res=[0,0,0], uls=document.querySelectorAll('form ul');  
  questions.forEach((qo,i)=>{ var a;
    if (a=uls[i].querySelector("input:checked")){ // only if an answer has been chosen
      let pts=qo.a.find(([el])=>el==a.value)[1]   // get array with points for all tests
      res.forEach((r,i)=>res[i]+=pts[i]);         // add points to res-array
    }    
  }); 
  res.forEach((r,i)=>spans[i].textContent=r)
};
```

```html
<h1>Test for Stroke and Diabetes</h1>

<form name="combitest">
  <p> Score for test 1 (Stroke) =   <span class="res"></span><br><br>
  <p> Score for test 2 (Diabetes) = <span class="res"></span><br><br>
  <p> Score for test 3 (some other test) = <span class="res"></span><br><br>
  <input type="reset" value="Clear Answers">
</form>
```

Comment: if I was adding another input to a question giving 3 possible answers for example, with the added intention of scoring lets say the first answer with the highest marks, the 2nd with a moderate and the last i would leave as blank. How could the selector be changed to look for multiple answers for a test? @cars10m

Comment: As an example I added the question "Body mass index" with three possible answer options. Two of which will be scoring points. It is now up to you to assign meaningful points for each answer option.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63505655/css-not-working-when-label-tag-placed-before-input-tag/63505719#63505719 ,not sure if the tag worked on the other page, if so apologies for the repetition. @cars10m

Comment: Hey @Lamtheram, what about this question? Do you consider it answered? If so, it would be nice if you could accept the answer here.